# Are there differences between the postal and postal-address python libraries?

Tags: python, parsing, libraries

Are there differences between the [postal](https://pypi.org/project/postal/) (the bindings for the C libpostal library) and [postal-address](https://pypi.org/project/postal-address/) python libraries?

Based on what I've read, there seem to be a few installation issues with postal/libpostal, and I take it you need to install the C library, not just the bindings (?). So could it be possible to replace one with the other?

Postal-address: "Python module to parse, normalize and render postal addresses."

Libpostal: "A C library for parsing/normalizing street addresses around the world."

These two libraries """seem""" set for the same task... But since I haven't seen anyone anywhere asking this same question, I fear I might be badly mistaken. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ensure tags are focused on immediate relevancy (especially with language tags..)